# Bokeh callback not updating chart

Tags: python, bokeh

I created a bokeh chart with a slider and textinput boxes that the user can use to adjust values. There is also an update button that the user can use to refresh the plot once they input the values they want. Everything is plotting fine but the data on the plot isn't updating when they hit update.

I have a callback with the "update" function that is supposed to refresh the data. Where am I going wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import bokeh
from os.path import dirname, join

from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.layouts import column,layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Div, Select, Slider, TextInput, Range1d, BasicTickFormatter, NumeralTickFormatter, Button, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.tickers import SingleIntervalTicker
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.events import ButtonClick

# Description text

desc = Div(text=open(join(dirname(__file__), "description.html")).read(), sizing_mode="stretch_width")

# Defining data input

age_input = Slider(title="Age", value = 30, start = 20, end = 67, step = 1)
salary_input = TextInput(title="Current Salary")
savings_input = TextInput(title = "Current Savings")

# Dummy values to start

age = 30
salary = 60000
salaryatret = (salary)*np.power(1.029, 67-age)
savings = 100000

# Loading goal data

goalbyage = pd.read_csv('goalbyage.csv', sep = ',', header = 0, index_col = 0)
specificgoal = goalbyage*salaryatret
specificgoal = specificgoal.round(decimals = 0)
specificgoal = specificgoal.astype(int)

# Update function for inputs

ages = specificgoal.index.tolist()
goals = specificgoal['goal'].tolist()

def update():
    age = age_input.value
    salary = int(salary_input.value or 0)
    savings = int(savings_input.value or 0)
    salaryatret = (salary)*np.power(1.029, 67-age)
    specificgoal = goalbyage*salaryatret
    specificgoal = specificgoal.round(decimals = 0)
    specificgoal = specificgoal.astype(int)
    ages = specificgoal.index.tolist()
    goals = specificgoal['goal'].tolist()

button = Button(label = "Update", background = "lightblue")
button.on_event(ButtonClick, update)

controls = [salary_input, age_input, savings_input, button]

plot = figure(plot_height = 500, plot_width = 800)
plot.vbar(x = ages, width = 0.8, bottom = 0, top = goals, color = "mediumseagreen")
plot.circle(x = age, y = savings, size = 15, color = "navy")

plot.xaxis.axis_label = "Age"
plot.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "10pt"
plot.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "14pt"
plot.x_range = Range1d(20,68)
plot.xaxis.ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval = 5, num_minor_ticks = 4)


plot.yaxis.axis_label = "Savings"
plot.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "10pt"
plot.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "14pt"
plot.y_range = Range1d(0,10*salaryatret)
plot.yaxis.formatter = BasicTickFormatter(use_scientific=False)
plot.yaxis.formatter=NumeralTickFormatter(format="$0,0")


percgoal = savings/(specificgoal.loc[age]['goal'])
percgoal = percgoal.round(decimals = 2)

inputs = column(controls, width=320, height=500)
inputs.sizing_mode = "fixed"
l = layout([
    [desc],
    [inputs, plot]])


curdoc().add_root(l)
```

Comment: Your callback creates local variables and doesn't override any globals. Even if it did, Bokeh models already have the values internally. You should change those values instead, using references to Bokeh models.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, thank you for replying. The variables referenced in the function are pre-defined outside the function and just have their values updated by the function so I'm not sure how to make sure the function overrides the global variables. How can I rewrite my code to make it correct?

Comment: You're not updating their values, you're just creating local variables with the same name. It's called "variable shadowing". To understand what I mean by "changing Bokeh models", take a look at any of the Bokeh examples that use widgets at https://demo.bokeh.org/ and take note of how they update the values from the outer scope.